# What is an alternative to this XML layout (Lint Warning)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-lint

Alright here it is, this layout will give you **3 images that are all of equal width, that width being as wide as the longest text** on the 3 textviews.

They are equal width because they match_parent and the parent is wrap_content to the largest TextView.

The 3 text views are centered on the background with equals space on the left and right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#FF0000"
         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:text="view 1"/>

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#FF0000"
         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:text="view 2"/>

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#FF0000"
         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
         android:text="view 3 longer text"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Like so:

[image: Preview]

**The problem is Lint is giving a warning that the inner LinearLayout is useless.** (Which it isn't because it's what makes the inner textviews become all the same width.

[image: Lint error]

Can anyone produce the same layout but without the lint warning?

Comment: The inner LinearLayout wrap's the textviews allowing the smaller TextViews to stretch to the size of the widest TextView. Whilst not stretching to the width of the screen

Comment: a tricky way to avoid the lint warning is adding a textview or another widget element with its visibility set to gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="view 1"/>

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="view 2"/>

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="view 3 longer text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This gives me similar results, without any error from Lint. I have removed the drawable tags from the code because i didnt have your drawables to use. Just add them. The only problem here is that you cant put a background in the LinearLayout tag. You will have to create a custom theme for your activity, which is quite easy as you can set an existing theme as a parent, and just change the background value... more on themes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.htm)

Comment: This is a good solution which allows you to reduce the complexity of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah it's just the question of is it worth creating a Theme just for one Activity. Perhaps I should ask why I am using this background and can I use it elsewhere to expand my Theme use. So at the end of the day I think this is the answer.

Comment: @Blundell you emphasise a lot on **creating a new theme** . If you actually write it, it comes to just three lines of code, five at max. So it isn't too much of work.

Comment: @udiboy It's not the lines of code, it's the point that creating a theme unique to one Activity doesn't seem the right thing to do. So I've re-evaluated my Activity and what I'm trying to achieve and created a theme that encompasses most the app. That is more like it.

Answer (score 1):

After much deliberation ... here's my solution which is to change the outer linear layout to a frame layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000FF" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="view 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="view 2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="view 3 longer text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

You can either set the layout gravity on the lineaer layout as:

`android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

or set the regular gravity on the frame layout.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is only a warning, and you know the layout isn't useless, you could just ignore it.

Alternatively, you can trick lint by adding `android:background="@null"` to the inner LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a RelativeLayout, within your Linear layout?